# Cannot cast 'ActionProvider' to 'MediaRouteActionProvider'

Tags: java, android-studio, chromecast

I'm creating my first Chromecast app and following [this](https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/android_sender) tutorial
I'm having trouble in my onCreateOptionsMenu method:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
    MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider =
            (MediaRouteActionProvider)MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);

    mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);
    return true;
}
```

It's throwing an error:

```
Incontrovertible types cannot cast 'android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider' to 'android.app.MediaRouteActionProvider'
```

I've extended `AppCompatActivity` rather than `ActionBarActivity`, I can't find a solution to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are importing MediaRouter from the MediaRouter support library and not the one from the android framework itself.

Comment: These are my imports: `import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter;`
`import android.app.MediaRouteActionProvider;`